# On Load, On Resize and On Scroll - what's the best way to run separate functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Load, On Resize and On Scroll - what's the best way to run separate functions?

I have a few functions, all do different parts throughout the website. Some for a parallax effect, some for a gallery etc..

At the moment I am grouping them in 3 separate 'on..' functions (as below). It works, but I'm sure there's a better way?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // on load functions go here

  $(window).on("load resize", function () {
    // on load and on resize functions go here
  });

  $(window).on("load resize scroll", function () {
    // on load, resize and scroll functions go here
  });

});
```

Comment: not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here, why do you need to bind `load` and `resize` twice?

Comment: If there are three different functionalities, what you're doing is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(myFunction1);

myFunction1 () {

  // on load functions go here

  $(window).on("load resize", myFunction1);

  $(window).on("load resize scroll", myFunction2);

}

function myFunction2(){
// on load and on resize functions go here
};

function myFunction3(){
// on load, resize and scroll functions go here
};
```

Comment: I've moved the function execution below the function, but I like this way the best.

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestions here and continuing my search, the best solution seems to be:

```
function load() {
});

function loadResize() {
});

function loadResizeScroll() {
});

$(window)
  .on('load', load)
  .on('load resize', loadResize)
  .on('load resize scroll', loadResizeScroll);
```